# Refactoring JScript code

Tags: javascript

How can I make this code into a one line instruction?

```
var qe : QuestionnaireElement = state.Parameters["demobreak"];

var qid : String = qe.QuestionId;

qid != "q45" 

public class QuestionnaireElement : ParameterValue, IParameterValue, ICloneabl
```

My real question is:

How can I cast in JScript objects?

```
  ((QuestionnaireElement)state.Parameters["demobreak"]).QuestionId != "q45"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all of you if I make waste your time. I was kind of desesperate to find out the solution, and like always, once that seen the solution, everything looks easier.

The final answer is (or at least a solution is):

(QuestionnaireElement)(state.Parameters["demobreak"]).ValueId != report.DataSource.GetProject("ds0").CreateQuestionnaireElement("q45").ValueId

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but wouldn't

```
(state.Parameters["demobreak"]:QuestionnaireElement).QuestionId != "q45"
```

do it?

Comment: Sorry but I have comiple error:
Hide script Line 1 Column 54: Expected ')'
Hide script Line 1 Column 25: Type mismatch

Comment: if the answer helped you, how about an upvote. If not, it would be great if you shared your solution? :)